# How to move my jupyter notebook setup to another PC

Tags: docker, anaconda, jupyter

I have made a sign lang detector on my PC and I am trying to move it to another remote PC. I can't solve the errors remotely because the PC is too slow, I have solved all these errors while setup on my PC priorly, and downloaded my anaconda3 file in which I had solved the issues, on the remote PC, but it's still throwing the same errors. What I want to know is there a way that I can transfer my whole setup to another PC and it runs out of the box like it does on my PC.

What I mean for example is, my code threw an error `tf has no attribute contrib`, I solved this on my PC in anaconda3 file. Now, I copied my anaconda3 file to another PC and run the same, and it is still throwing the same error.

Now How can I simply transfer my setup to another PC, because I have multiple such errors I already resolved and running, working, code on one of my PC. Plus the remote connection to the other PC is too slow, so I can't solve the issues even if I wanted to.

Comment: What is your "anaconda3 file"?

Comment: @FlyingTeller anaconda3 is the name of the file from which the anaconda app boots up, it has all the packages you install too. My bad for not clarifying as I thought it would be common knowledge as you need to make changes in it if you want to customize any packages.